# Tsocks not working with Java

Tags: java, tsocks

I have defined following Sock5 proxies using TSocks. Following is my Tsocks file

```
local = 192.168.5.0/255.255.255.0

# Otherwise we use the server
server = 192.168.5.1

#HKG
path {
server = localhost
server_port = 8082
reaches = 10.110.80.0/255.255.255.0
server_type = 5
}

#DCA
path {
server = localhost
server_port = 8081
reaches = 10.125.4.0/255.255.255.0
server_type = 5
}
```

Now `tsocks telnet IP PORT` is working, However Java is not able to get proxy as `tsocks java class` is giving connection time out when connecting with IP at PORT

How to make Java to pick this proxy setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering my Question**

This is a known bug with tsocks. Tsock won't work with any application which uses Poll to to wait at a socket. JVM and Chrome are two examples. Following link has the description of the bug and a patch to fix -

[Tsock poll bug patch](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=576301)

*Patch is not official and Tsocks official repository is dead form 10 years. It would be better to use ProxyChains if possible*

**EDIT:** Patch is not working. However the problem is same as listed in the bug report. I will come up with my own patch

Comment: Do you known solution for tsocks + java?

Comment: Hi,
As mentioned in the edited post, last time I tried the patch wasn't working :(
I have changed my problem statement to completely erase the need of tsocks. Btw, you could try Proxy chains. I read that its working with Java

Comment: I also have tried proposed patches and they are had not working for me. It is why I ask. ProxyChains unfortunately can't setup "paths" in terms of tsocks configuration. To define proxies only for chosen destinations.

Comment: Proxychains doesn't properly support java either.